# how to set the bash scripts with in the python scripts rather than having separate scripts?

Tags: python, bash, shell, environment-variables, environ

This is how I running the bash script set in **myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', '/bin/bash myscript.sh'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
output=child.communicate()
print(output)
```

***myscript.sh***

Why am I making this is because the bash script that I have to run does not have the export command so I am echoing here. Code bellow. I know echoing wont set the environment variable but I just want to echo it and fetch the value so echoing instead of exporting.

```
#!/bin/bash
source ia_servers
echo $IA_SRV_cs68_64
```

*Where*, *$IA_SRV_cs68_64*

Here is the ia_servers file where the variable values are listed
it looks something like this

```
IA_SRV_cs68_64="ds1 ds2 ds3 ds5 "
```

This is how the variables are in it. Many other variable are set in it eliminated because too longer.

**TESTED works well from terminal:**

- **source ia_servers**
- **echo IA_SRV_cs68_64**

prints the desired values set

**Problem:**
Though **myscript.sh** is working and printing the variables . What I want is I don't want to create a separate file write a bash script there to echo the variable as in the myscript.sh but  instead write it within the python.

> How do I accomplish it within the python rather rather than making the
>   script file and run that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a universal way to run any kind of script or program where program input is embedded in the Python script.

```
import subprocess
scriptres = subprocess.Popen("/bin/bash", 
                             stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(r'''
# your bash script here
ls
pwd
source whatever
echo $SOMETHING
''')

script_stdout = scriptres[0]
script_stderr = scriptres[1]
```

Comment: What I did is the same. My requirements are different

Answer (score 0):

```
# i assume there is a file by name `ia_servers` with variable IA_SRV_cs68_64="ds1 ds2 ds3 ds5 "

import imp
ia_servers =imp.load_source('ia_servers', 'path to `ia_servers` file')

print ia_servers.IA_SRV_cs68_64 # this should print `ds1 ds2 ds3 ds5`
```

Comment: I think you can do this even without using a bash script. is this what you want?

Comment: That file path has the environment source. Want to load that and echo our the variables . TRYING this approach says
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IA_SRV_cs68_64'

Comment: This error is because you were not able to import the ia_servers, I had misspelt it last time.

Comment: I tried with correct names.
>>> import  imp
>>> ias_server=imp.load_source('ias_servers',' ./ ') #alsotried with' .'
>>> print(ias_server.IA_SRV_cs68_64) 
Still same

Comment: checked with dir(). It has no such attributes. Also checked if it is a path issue since the ias_servers is in the same path i tried '.' and also './' no effects

Comment: yes i tested with proper variable in before . the variable i don't think need to be same as the fie name i have added my code in comment above

Comment: I got it but your file should be same

Comment: in your comment your file name is ias_servers were as in question it says ia_servers

Comment: Tried again, same problem that attribute does not exist. The problem comes in print statement . No such attribute exist. Means the load_source was success but it doesnot have anything to do with IA_SRV_cs68_64

Comment: change this  ias_server=imp.load_source('ias_servers',' ./ ')   to ias_server=imp.load_source('ias_servers',' ./ia_servers')     you need to give full path ,second argument is path upto file, also try giving absolute path of the file.

Comment: Now I am getting different errors not in our code but in the basscript file

Comment: why do you need as bash script

Comment: Thats where the server list and groups are set which my python application can access

Comment: what i just want to accomplish is what is successfully done from the terminal Getting the values. GETTING some syntax related errors

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.